# should one or multiple sqs client be used to receive and delete messages?

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

I'd like to create two functions receive_message and delete_message from the same sqs queue. Should I use the same sqs client for receiving and deleting or I can use different ones? Is there any overhead of creating a new sqs client that matters in terms of speed and performance?

I did two tests.

Test 1 is to use different sqs clients in receive and delete message function. and I recorded the time elapsed.

Test 2 is to use same sqs clients for receiving and deleting and I also recorded the time elapsed

test1:

```
def receive_delete_message():
    """Receive message from SQS"""
    sqs = boto3.client("sqs")
    queue_url = "my sqs url"
    response = sqs.receive_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        AttributeNames=[
            'SentTimestamp'
        ],
        MaxNumberOfMessages=10,  # [1, 10] default is 1, 10 is desired
        MessageAttributeNames=[
            'All'
        ],
        VisibilityTimeout=1,  # default is 30sec
        WaitTimeSeconds=20  # [0, 20]. short poll if 0, otherwise long poll
    )
    if "Messages" not in response:  # empty sqs queue
        print("empty queue")
        return
    messages = response["Messages"]
    for i, message in enumerate(messages):
        receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']
        print("this is message {}, {}".format(i+1, message["Body"]))
        delete_message(receipt_handle)

def delete_message(receipt_handle):
    sqs2 = boto3.client("sqs")
    queue_url = "my sqs url"
    sqs2.delete_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle
    )
    print("message deleted")

start = time.time()
receive_delete_message()
print(time.time() - start)
```

test 2:

```
sqs = boto3.client("sqs")
queue_url = "my sqs url"


def receive_delete_message():
    """Receive message from SQS"""
    response = sqs.receive_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        AttributeNames=[
            'SentTimestamp'
        ],
        MaxNumberOfMessages=10,  # [1, 10] default is 1, 10 is desired
        MessageAttributeNames=[
            'All'
        ],
        VisibilityTimeout=1,  # default is 30sec
        WaitTimeSeconds=20  # [0, 20]. short poll if 0, otherwise long poll
    )
    if "Messages" not in response:  # empty sqs queue
        print("empty queue")
        return
    messages = response["Messages"]
    for i, message in enumerate(messages):
        receipt_handle = message['ReceiptHandle']
        print("this is message {}, {}".format(i+1, message["Body"]))
        delete_message(receipt_handle)


def delete_message(receipt_handle):
    sqs.delete_message(
        QueueUrl=queue_url,
        ReceiptHandle=receipt_handle
    )
    print("message deleted")


start = time.time()
receive_delete_message()
print(time.time() - start)
```

result from test 1:

```
this is message 1, message1000
message deleted
this is message 2, message1002
message deleted
this is message 3, message1003
message deleted
this is message 4, message1004
message deleted
this is message 5, message1007
message deleted
this is message 6, message1008
message deleted
this is message 7, message1018
message deleted
this is message 8, message1025
message deleted
this is message 9, message1034
message deleted
this is message 10, message1036
message deleted
1.526839017868042
```

result from test 2

```
this is message 1, message1002
message deleted
this is message 2, message1013
message deleted
this is message 3, message1017
message deleted
this is message 4, message1028
message deleted
this is message 5, message1029
message deleted
this is message 6, message1044
message deleted
this is message 7, message1047
message deleted
this is message 8, message1005
message deleted
this is message 9, message1006
message deleted
this is message 10, message1015
message deleted
0.5138881206512451
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd have to run this test 100s of times to get meaningful data, in my opinion. The primary reasons to employ multiple clients are that you want to target multiple AWS regions or use multiple sets of AWS credentials. In this case, I would just use a single client.

Answer (score 0):

You are basically making a second object that has access to the exact same permissions as the first. The credentials are the same.

If you are considering deleting the message from a client (2 Lambdas maybe) other than the receiving consumer then, you are TRUSTING that the receiving consumer will ALWAYS succeed and delete the message. What happens if the consumer fails and you delete the message from the queue?

I also second what jarmod says. Seeing a 1 off ~1 second difference is not a meaningful performance benchmark. Overall, a single Lambda consumer that reads from the queue is good for a small use-case. If you are really looking for something production ready, I would look at something like: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/userguide/as-using-sqs-queue.html